# Overlaying two SmoothDensityHistograms

Tags: plotting

I want to overlay two objects of SmoothDensityHistogram using Show, in order to highlight a region of the shared plot space.  However, the top object completely obscures the bottom one.  I tried to set an opacity for the objects, but SmoothDenstiyHistogram does not accept PlotStyle as an argument to pass either Opacity[...] or Directive[Opacity[...]].  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Could you post example code of your histograms?

Comment: @CarlLange My histograms are generated from large data files, but any two sets of random data passed into a SmoothDensityHistogram and overlaid will show the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `ColorFunction` to use `Opacity`.

Let's define our `ColorFunction`, which basically just returns a color for a given plot value:

```
cf[z_] := Opacity[z, RGBColor[z, 1 - z, 1]]
```

(You can also wrap any of the `ColorData` functions with that `Opacity` and it should work)

Now we can use that to show two plots together:

```
s1 = SmoothDensityHistogram[
  RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.2], 10], PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, 
  Frame -> None, ColorFunction -> cf]
s2 = SmoothDensityHistogram[
  RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 10], PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, 
  Frame -> None, ColorFunction -> cf]

Overlay[{s1, s2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Do you not want to have something like `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`?  Otherwise, the highest values have the same color even if there's a large difference in the "peakedness" of the two densities?

Comment: @JimB That's a good point - probably a good idea to add your own answer working around that issue.